# javascript calculating scrollbar height

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, percentage

I read some threads here about how to get the height of the scrollbar, and the answers where "use percentage". But whats the best way to calculate it without bugs?

The math "bugs" are already known, e.g 10 / 15 = 0.666666, this problem would return strange scrollbar heights... So whats the best way to avoid this, and to get the percentage of

height = x% from scrollHeight ?

Thank you.

Comment: These types of errors can be reduced by completing division at the last possible moment. Most of the time the error is small enough not to worry about, though

Answer (score -2):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document

screen.height; //for screen height
screen.width; //for screen width
```

in your case

```
$(window).height(); // length y s.bar
$(window).width(); // length x s.bar
```

Comment: i dondt think you understood my question. Firts i dont want to use jquery, and second the scrollbar height isnt as height as the browser height.